# Why can't I add comment?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Why can't I add comment on posts in Stackoverflow.com? It seems that whenever I post a question I can add comments, while on other's posts I cannot comment at all. Why is this so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have enough reputation to post comments on questions other than yours.

The [privilege is earned at 50 reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment), so only two/four more upvotes to go!

Comment: Oh I see. Even for comments you need reputations! That's good only in a way. Thanks :)

Comment: @Shill - Well, it means that spammers can't spam without gaining some reputation first. And it is not a huge hurdle - a couple of good answers and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks guys :) appreciate the prompt answer.

Comment: @Shill - Looks like you now do have the reputation needed on Stack Overflow. Enjoy your commenting :)